# Conditionally append elements from parsed JSON that match a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm looking to append elements conditionally to a container based on whether the tags data matches the key variable.

The way tags' data is returned is like tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 tag5, the key is matching some of the tags data but it still isn't doing the conditional append.

Any kind of help with this headache would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the code:

```
var key = getParameterByName('img');

var tags = item.tags;

        if (key != null){
          //move onto conditional append

          if (key === tags) {

        $('<div class="photo">
           <figure class="cell" data="'+tags+'">
           <figcaption class="caption" style="display: none;"> '+title+' <a href="">click</a></figcaption>
           <a href="' +imgb+ '"><img src="' +img+ '" class="small-image"/></a></figure>').appendTo('#container');
          }
        }
        else {
        $('<div class="photo"><figure class="cell" data="'+tags+'"><figcaption class="caption" style="display: none;">'+title+'<a href="">click</a></figcaption><a href="'+imgb+'"><img src="'+img+'" class="small-image"/></a></figure>').appendTo('#container');
      }
```

Comment: What is `key`?.

Comment: key is a variable that's trigged on page load.

var key = getParameterByName('img');

Comment: `the key is matching some of the tags ` does that mean if tags is `tag1 tag2 tag3` then key could be `tag1 tag2` ?

Comment: Try to console log your `key` and `tags` variable and see what they are

Comment: No key would be more like tag3 matches tag3 from tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4

Comment: it sounds like you may need to try

`(tags.includes(key))`

instead of

`(key === tags)`

Comment: You my friend are a life saver! Thank you.

Comment: No problem.  Please mark as correct if that helped you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (tags.includes(key)) instead of (key === tags).  You are checking if a string is included in a larger string, not if "tag1 tag2 tag3" is exactly equal to "tag1."

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the loop thru the tags array, and then comparing inside the loop to see if the tag matches your `key`. Also, the html you are building dynamically inside the `$('--html here--')` is not valid HTML (you have open elements).

```js
(function($){$(function(){
  var key = 'tag2';
  var tags = ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'];

  if (key != null){
    //move onto conditional append
    tags.map(function(tag, k){
      if (key === tag) {
        $('<div class="photo">The tag value is ' + tag + '</div>').appendTo('#container');
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    $('<div class="photo">The tag key is null</div>').appendTo('#container');
  }

})})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Ohhhhh! By reading your question again seems like `tags` is a string not an array. If that's the case, then see below.

```js
(function($){$(function(){
  var key = 'tag3';
  var tags = 'tag1 tag2 tag3';

  if (key != null){
    //move onto conditional append
    if (tags.includes(key)) {
        $('<div class="photo">The tag value is ' + key + '</div>').appendTo('#container');
    }
    else {
        $('<div class="photo">The tag value is ' + key + ' but is not in the list of tags</div>').appendTo('#container');
    }
  }
  else {
    $('<div class="photo">The tag key is null</div>').appendTo('#container');
  }

})})(jQuery)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```